# Recursion function (with bit shift)

Tags: python, bit-shift

```
def recursion(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return x << 1 + recursion(x - 1)

print(recursion(3)) # 393216


print(3 << 1) # 6
print(2 << 1) # 4
print(1 << 1) # 2
```

In my head the output of the recursion function should be: 12 *(6+4+2)*
Why is this not the case? I must say "393216" is slightly bigger than my expected number "12".

**My expectation:**

```
--> return 1<<1==2 for 1
--> return 2<<1==4 for 2
--> return 3<<1==6 for 3
0 --> return 0 for 0
```

All together = 12

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is due to operator precedence. Bitshift operators have lower precedence than arithmetic.

By default, `x << 1 + recursion(x - 1)` is assumed to be `x << (1 + recursion(x - 1))`.

You can fix the issue by overriding the default precedence using parentheses.

```
def recursion(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return (x << 1) + recursion(x - 1)

print(recursion(3)) # 12
```

Answer (score 4):

Operator precedence. Bit shifts have lower precedence than addition/subtraction ([see in docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)). Hence you need

```
def recursion(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return (x << 1) + recursion(x - 1)
```

as currently your function is being interpreted equivalent to

```
def recursion(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return x << (1 + recursion(x - 1))
```

Comment: Quick correction, bitshifts have lower precedence, not stronger.